# Hide decimal for a whole number with Excel Custom Formatting

Tags: excel, custom-formatting

I'm trying to use a [custom format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx) to a group of cells so that decimals are permitted, but whole numbers are shown when used.

For example, here's some sample input and desired output:

```
2   --> 2 day(s)
1.5 --> 1.5 day(s)
```

If I use a number format with a decimal place, I always get the decimal point.

```
###.# " day(s)";;@
2 --> 2. day(s)
```

If I don't use a decimal place, then it always rounds.

```
### " day(s)";;@
1.5 --> 2 day(s)
```

Is there a way to conditionally add the decimal point?

Comment: The General format works as you describe. Also, should your title say "Hide decimal"?

Comment: @DougGlancy Then the thousands separator is lost.